# How do I get my displayed SQL value update automatically? The 'after()' option does not have the intended results - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am seeing partial results with the 'after()' in the main definition however the updated result is not passed on to the main display. Placing a call to the 'after()' specified definition works the same as if the 'after()' syntax wasn't in place.

I need the display track to update as changes occur to the database. My intention was to set the interval to 1000.  Please help.

```
def commquery():

    # Database Call
    dbi = mdb.connect("localhost", port=3306, user="access", passwd="pass", db="interactive_db")
    cursor = dbi.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT dept,name FROM active""")
    dbi.commit()
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    cpt = 0  
    for row in row:
        track.insert('', 'end', values=(row[0], row[1]))
        cpt += 1  # increment the ID
    cursor.close()
    print (cursor)
   print (row)
    #root.after(10, commquery)  # when uncommented it works but does not update entry

def selfupdate():
    root.after(20, commquery) # when called it works oncecommtrack =  ttk.Treeview(queryFrame)



root = Tk()
track = ttk.Treeview(queryFrame)
track["columns"] = ("one", "two")
track.column("one", width=40)
track.column("two", width=70)
track.configure(show='')
track.configure(height='1')
track.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="W", padx=5)
selfupdate() # updates the once


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code on Stackoverflow. Without correct indentions your code is useless.

Comment: you forgot `root.mainloop()` - without `mainloop()` program may not work.

Comment: `20ms` is very short time - you will no see difference if you use bigger value - ie. `200ms` or `500ms` - but program will use less CPU.

Comment: `for row in row:` is not good idea - use two different names - ie `for row in all_rows:`

Comment: please fix the indentation of your code. It's impossible to know which lines belong to each function.

Comment: after fixing indentions and adding `root.mainloop() (and changes with grid  to see full treeview) I works for me without problems.

Comment: Sorry I did not include the root.mainloop though it is in my script.  I have updated the script info to show it.  I also fixed the display to show proper indenting as in my script.  - I will need to check display more carefully in the future

Comment: I dont understand 'use button {} to correctly format code '. Do I need to enable the use of a button?

Comment: you have to add 4 spaces before every line of code - if you select code when you edit question and use button `{}` in editor then it adds 4 spaces to all selected lines - and you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: I tried code and don't have problem - it adds new rows to TreeView (or rather it adds the same rows again and again because I don't delete older rows). There is no scrollbar in TreeView but using mouse wheel I can see all rows.

Comment: Aah.  So I am using the wrong code as I want to refresh the top row as I only display one row. Is there a way with the tree syntax?

Comment: I solved it by using Listbox, doing a delete(o, end) then using fetchone() in DEF finally box.insert("end",row). So when after() kicked in display refreshed with  Mysql current data.

Comment: @Raymond If you managed to find a solution. Please provide it as an answer using below textbox here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by clearing out the listbox first at the top of the Definition.

```
myListbox.delete(0, end)
```

at the end of the query used

```
cursor.fetchone()
....
myListbox.insert("end",row)
```

So when after() kicked in display refreshed with Mysql current data.